# Return value of og the method is never used

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods

```
public class prime {
    public static String method(int n){
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <n-1 ; i++) {
            if (n%i==0)
                ++cnt;
        }
        if (cnt==0)
            return "YES";
        else
            return "NO";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(10);

    }
}
```

IntelliJ is saying to me when i hover over name of my method that `Return value of og the method is never used` and when i hover over name of this method in main i get this message `Result of 'prime.method()' is ignored` and i dont know why. Any help? Also in console i get nothing. Just Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: `String result = method(10);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called `method()`, and it will return a `String(YES or NO)`, but the return value was ignored. So IntelliJ IDEA reminds you to use it.

For example, print it:

```
String result = method(10);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling "method". It is returning a String. You do not assign it to a variable, i.e.

```
String value =  method(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods can return values in Java, meaning they give a value back to the calling method. Your method "method(int)" returns a String to the main method.

However, the main method doesn't use the returned value.
If you want to print the value, you can use the following main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(method(10));
}
```